# Why is python allowing me to create variable with reserved keywords?

Tags: python, variables, python-3.6

I ran this code and i was able to assign value to a reserved keyword. Why python allows assignment statements to reserved keyword or am i doing something wrong?

screenshot 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEd7y.jpg

int = 7
print(int)
7
:

int(int)

error

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 int(int)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: Like many programming languages, Python gives you enough rope to hang yourself. Any programming language is a compromise between flexibility and safety. Just how that plays out in a particular case depends in part upon the design goals of the language.

Comment: That is not a Python keyword. Here are the Python keywords: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords

Answer (score 6):

`int` is not a reserved keyword, it's just the name of a builtin function.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between *reserved keywords* and *builtins*.

Builtins, like `int`, `str`, and `float`, are actually just commonly used classes. Classes can be reassigned/overridden, and that's exactly what you did here by writing `int = 7`.

Keywords, like `as`, `if`, and `while`, are very special identifiers. These cannot be overridden. If you attempted to write `as = 10`, you would get a `SyntaxError`.

Here's the reason behind your error: first, you gave `int` the value `7`. This is completely legal because builtins can be reassigned. After doing that, typing `int(int)` is like typing `7(7)`. `7` cannot be called like a function, so this results in a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an IDE like pyCharm, it will give you a warning if one of your variables shares a name with a builtin or keyword.